# Is there a lint like program for crontab?

Tags: syntax, cron, system-administration, lint

Is there anything like lint for crontab? I'd like to know that i've got all my spaces and stars sorted out without waiting for something to not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need a lint for crontab.  There's 5 fields that are space separated then a space then the command to run and its args finish off the line.

Also, on Ubuntu at least, crontab won't let you save a bum file.  I just tried a few things and it barfed on all of them.  I guess that means that crontab is its own 'lint for cron'.

Comment: Most crons also require a newline at the end of the file.  And not everybody installs cron entries interactively.  If you are using some sort of automation or large scale configuration management system, you'll be able to easily/accidentally bypass any sanity checks that the system has as a defense mechanism.  I'd strongly argue that lint for cron is an abundantly reasonable idea.  (Indeed, searching for one is how I found this old question.)

Comment: On Ubuntu you also need to provide the username after the time fields

Answer (score 10):

There's a Python linter for crons. See [`chkcrontab` project](https://pypi.org/project/chkcrontab/)

You can install it via `pip`:

```sh
pip3 install chkcrontab
```

Example usage:

```sh
chkcrontab /etc/cron.d/power-schedule
Checking correctness of /etc/cron.d/power-schedule
E: 15: 0 12 * foo * * root echo hi
e:     FIELD_VALUE_ERROR: foo is not valid for field "month" (foo)
e:     INVALID_USER: Invalid username "*"
E: There were 2 errors and 0 warnings.
```

Comment: The [chkcrontab](https://github.com/lyda/chkcrontab) is now on Github and on [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/chkcrontab/)

Answer (score 8):

I've found [CronWTF](http://cronwtf.github.com/) to be incredibly helpful when writing crontabs - it translates your stars and commands into something more human friendly, to make it easier to read strange cron jobs.

Better yet, because it's all javascript you can run it locally, and noone need know about your top sekrit cron jobs.

Another alternative if you code ruby is to use the [whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever) gem - you use a sample ruby file called `schedule.rb` to parse, and generate crontabs from like so:

```
every 10.minutes do
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command" 
end
```

Will give you a crontab entry of

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /usr/bin/my_great_command
```

And this one here:

```
every 2.days, :at => '4:30am' do
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command" 
end
```

Will give you:

```
30 4 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31 * * /usr/bin/my_great_command
```

Comment: The link is broken. Same as [this](https://github.com/technoweenie/cronwtf) → [cronwtf.dev](https://cronwtf.dev/)?

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit off, but an easy way would be to just load it with a graphical crontab editor like kcron or gcrontab. If you need to call it in a script, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235504/validating-crontab-entries-w-php) is about how to do it in php.

Comment: ssh admin@myhost kcron
Error: cannot open display

Not everyone has a GUI.

Comment: Well, you almost certainly have a GUI somewhere. Use ssh X forwarding and voilà - The window appears on your screen

Comment: Not if you're on one of my servers it won't.  Installing enough X libs (plus GTK/Qt/KDElibs/etc) to get a graphical editor is a no-no on a serious server.  Size reasons aside, we like to keep off everything that can present a possible attack vector.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the sort of thing you're looking for, but it makes writing crontabs really easy by showing you exactly what you're setting the schedule to:

https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Yes, yes it does. I wish I would have had that for the last... 25 years?

Comment: I hear ya...by this point I'm sure I've wasted a fair amount of time re-teaching every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try shell script named `48-verifycron` from [Wicked Cool Shell Scripts, 2nd Edition](https://nostarch.com/wcss2/),
if you can't access python and pip to use `chkcrontab`