# Why Quartz says this cron expression is not valid?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Quartz 2.x [documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger) says

> So cron expressions can be as simple as this: * * * * ? * or more
>   complex, like this: 0/5 14,18,3-39,52 * ? JAN,MAR,SEP MON-FRI
>   2002-2010

But if I try

```
System.out.println(org.quartz.CronExpression.isValidExpression("* * * * ? * *"));
```

It says

```
false
```

Why?

Javadoc for the isValidExpression is http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronExpression.html

Ps. this question is NOT a duplicate of [Verifying a cron expression is valid in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362985/verifying-a-cron-expression-is-valid-in-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The linked [JavaDoc](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronExpression.html) mentions this structure for cron expressions:

```
Field Name      Allowed Values       Allowed Special Characters

Seconds         0-59                 , - * /
Minutes         0-59                 , - * /
Hours           0-23                 , - * /
Day-of-month    1-31                 , - * ? / L W
Month           1-12 or JAN-DEC      , - * /
Day-of-Week     1-7 or SUN-SAT       , - * ? / L #
Year (Optional) empty, 1970-2199     , - * /
```

Your cron expression is `"* * * * ? * *"` with a `?` on the 5th position for `Month`. As you can see, this character is **not** allowed there.

Answer (score 4):

The JavaDoc you mentioned states that the `?` character is allowed only for *day-of-month* and *day-of-week* fields. You are using it in *Month* field.