# Do you know any library or code in PHP to check if a date satisfies a given cron expression?

Tags: php, date, cron

I was wondering if some of you know about a library in php so that I can pass a date and a cron expression and it tells me wether the date satisfies the cron expression or not. The java Quartz library is able to do that (and more like getting the next valid date for a given cron expression) but I was wondering if this is possible using php.

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for this code, but there's a cron parser at [PHP Classes](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2568-PHP-Parse-cron-tab-files-to-retrieve-job-schedules.html).

And there's [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235504/validating-crontab-entries-w-php) that might be useful.