# How can I validate a cron expression in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I have  a GWT application which allows the user to enter a cron expression in a TextField. The cron expression is eventually used in a quartz scheduler on the server. I'm wondering is there a way I can validate the expression the user enters without going back to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform your own string parsing or apply a regex.

Take a look at this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235504/validating-crontab-entries-w-php).

Answer (score 0):

Use Bean validation JSR 303 for serverside validation. Here is an example on my blog about how to Write a custom validator for cron expressions
http://www.bagdemir.com/2011/04/27/bean-validation-jsr-303-and-validating-cron-expressions-extending-constraints/

Comment: Erhan, I think the question refers to client side validation. The link: http://www.bagdemir.com/2011/04/27/bean-validation-jsr-303-and-validating-cron-expressions-extending-constraints/ is not found.