# How do I make sure a cron job will run?

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I've always used cpanel to set up con jobs but I don't have cpanel now.
So I added a PHP file in the cron.hourly but I want to be sure it will run.
There must be some way to do this. Like a command that lists all the cron jobs that exist?
I am on Debian 7 64 bit.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7053/how-can-get-a-list-of-all-scheduled-cron-jobs-on-my-machine

Comment: So as long as they are in that dir they will for sure run. Correct?

Comment: I think may help. Try to get all the cronjobs, if yours there it will run for sure. Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating Crontab Entries w/ PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235504/validating-crontab-entries-w-php)

Comment: How would I see all cron jobs curently running?
Jason: This isn't about PHP. Yes the script being ran will be PHP but i'm asking for a command to run.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

If you use crontab -e the crontab job will be syntax-checked

If you are just editing `/etc/crontab`  or `/etc/cron.*/*` there is no automatic checking

nothing will check the code of your job will actually run successfully.

Comment: The code should run. As long as it is executed in the same dir. (I'm pretty sure crons do this?)
Iv'e tested them. I'm just hesitant I didn't do the crons right

Answer (score 0):

To list all cron jobs for a user:

```
crontab -u <user> -l
```

To list all cron jobs for root:

```
crontab -l
```